# SQL math with percent in an UPDATE

Tags: sql, drupal

In Holland, the VAT will be changed from 19% to 21%.

Now I have 4000 products in my webshop and want to change all the prices on the same time.

The prices are stored in a sql database. My question is: Is it possible to select my prices and update them with 2 percent extra?

Comment: That's one of the reasons you should store the net price, not the price including the VAT. That way you only need to update a single row in the table containing the VAT - and it's easier to manage products with different VATs - which is e.g. necessary in Germany

Answer (score 3):

It's not 2%.  You can convert it by dividing by the old rate, and multiplying by the new rate:

```
update  PriceTable
set     Price = Price / 1.19 * 1.21
```

Adds up to being a 1.68% increase.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ubercart or commerce module? If is the case, is easy with tax/vat configuration.